# How to change Maximum Zoom on Google Maps API, using GMAP3 jQuery plugin?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, jquery-gmap3

How to change Maximum Zoom on Google Maps API, using GMAP3 jQuery plugin?

Is there a {} setting for this thing?

Thanks for this.

Answer (score 1):

If it is not possible with GMAP3, you can still directly use the Google api:

```
map.setOptions({maxZoom: 10});
```